# Run function when other function is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking for a way to run a function when the other function is ready.

This is the function:

```
$(".box").first().show(150, function showNext () {

    $(this).next(".box").show(150, showNext);

});
```

So Im look for a way to run another function after that, for example:

```
alert("Done");
```

I've tried this but didn't work.

```
$(".box").first().show(150, function showNext () {

    $(this).next(".box").show(150, showNext);

}, function () {

alert("Done");

});
```

What I want is, in words:

```
if(all .box is visble or if showNext is idle/completed){

alert("Done");

}
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Just add an `if ($(this).next(".box").length === 0) { alert("Done"); } else `$(this).next(".box").show(150, showNext);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about :

```
$(".box").first().show(150, function showNext () {
    var next = $(this).next(".box");

    if (next.length > 0) { // If a next sibling with class "box" was found
        next.show(150, showNext);
    } else { // No sibling found, end reached
        alert("Done");
    }
});
```